# rspec to test respond_to format and csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I want to test if top_users eq User.top_users in my rspec controller. 
How do i access the format.csv? I need something like:

```rb
it "format csv" do
  get :index, format: :csv
  # expect(something)……
end
```

Later want to test the csv: if file format is correct, without saving/downloading it.

Controller:

```rb
def index
  respond_to do |format|  
    format.csv do
      top_users = User.top_users

      send_data(
        top_users.to_csv,
        filename: "top-users-#{Time.zone.today}.csv"
      )
    end
  end
end
```

Model:

```rb
def self.to_csv
  CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
    csv << [‘one’, ‘two’]

    all.each do |user|
      csv << user.csv_data
    end
  end
end
```

csv_data is: [user.name, user.email] or so…

Comment: What happened when you tried the example spec you have shown us here?

Comment: Ok, that's not the full error message... Can you please go to your logfiles (`log/test.log`) and rerun the spec, then find the error in there and show us a bit more?

One point: have you copied/pasted this code directly from your app? have you noticed that the code in your question has strange string-formatting? That's because there are strange "special" quotes being used in the code you've copied/pasted. It could plausibly be that the ruby interpreter is finding those quotes strange eg it's expecting `'` and finding `\`` instead and thinking the string isn't properly closed Also `"` vs `“`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It doesn't matter CSV, PDF or something else, it's all about the response that you get from the get request with format csv. 
This is way i do test my the csv generator:

```
describe "GET/index generate CSV" do
  before :each do
    get :index, format: :csv
  end

  it "generate CSV" do
    expect(response.header['Content-Type']).to include 'text/csv'
    expect(response.body).to include('what you expect the file to have')
  end
end
```

And that's it.

For each user that you have you can do something like this:

```
 User.top_users.each do |user|
   expect(response.body).to include(user.name) # or the attr you want to check if it's in the file
 end
```

you can also add 'pry' gem, put binding.pry before expect and see the response and what elements would be helpful for you to check if the method works correctly as you expect.

Comment: i copied your code and it gives me -> undefined method `request='

Comment: request=? Do you see any request method in my code or yours code!

Comment: The `format` argument is part of `ActionController::TestCase`, which is being aggressively deprecated. It is now recommended to use `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` which does not have a `format` argument.

Answer (score 3):

If you run into the error `unknown keyword: :format`, try this:

```rb
describe "GET/index generate CSV" do    
  it "generate CSV" do
    get :index, params: {format: :csv}
    expect(response.header['Content-Type']).to include 'text/csv'
    expect(response.body).to include('what you expect the file to have')
  end
end
```

Comment: Keyword `format` is unknown because it's only part of the deprecated test class `ActionController::TestCase` and we're being advised to switch to `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`.
`params: { format: :csv }` does work, but it is not idiomatic. The idiomatic solution is to use the `as: :csv` argument, but that requires registering the `csv` format so that Rails recognizes it.

Answer (score 0):

At least with Rails 7, there are a few things going on here:

1. What kind of test is being written? There is a subtle difference between the deprecated `ActionController::TestCase` and the new `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`. Both support the `as` argument but only the deprecated `ActionController::TestCase` supports the `format` argument.
2. The `as` argument will not accept `csv` out of the box. This is because content types need to be recognized by `ActionDispatch::RequestEncoder`, and at least for me, it only knows about :json, :identity, and :turbo_stream. YMMV.

To get Rails to recognize CSV format, you must register it like so:

`register_encoder :csv, param_encoder: -> params { params.to_s }`

Source:

- https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/IntegrationTest.html
- https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TestCase/Behavior.html#method-i-process
- https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.4/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb#L32